# MYSQL: Select a column that is named like the syntax

Tags: mysql

Im doing a simple MY SQL statement:

```
var sqlString = "SELECT videosplit FROM 10299_12188_tblVideos WHERE adId = " + adId + " AND order = " + order
```

But it fails at "order".

I believe it is because of the "order by" statement.  But hte column name is called "order". How can I fix this?

I tried putting "order" around these '' = "'order'". But that statement returns nothing, although it should give me something...

Best,

J

Comment: put the reserved words used as column names inside backtick `\`order\``

Comment: fantastic. please answer :)

Comment: Been answered many times before. See Duplicate

Comment: order - its a reserved keyword in mysql You should not use it

Comment: Yep, don't use reserved words as table/column identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

general syntax for order by is:

```
SELECT videosplit FROM 10299_12188_tblVideos ORDER BY adId;
```

in your case use order with backtick

Comment: No. I dont want to order by. The column name is "ORDER". And I need to select where COLUMN (ORDER) = xy. please read again.

Comment: use `order` with backtick